# Attempt to read property "id_tahun" on array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, eloquent

i try to transform it with eloquent, but the error pop-up
[Error Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmwnq.png)"Attempt to read property "id_tahun" on array"

```
$factpelanggan = DB::connection('clickhouse')
    ->select('SELECT id_tahun, t.tahun, l.id_lokasi
    from dim_tahun t, dim_lokasi l');

    foreach ($factpelanggan as $value) {
        $id_tahun[]=$value->id_tahun;
        $id_lokasi[]=$value->id_lokasi;
        $tahun[]=$value->tahun;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select query in Laravel returns an array: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database#running-a-select-query
You can change your code like that:

```
    foreach ($factpelanggan as $value) {
        $id_tahun[]=$value['id_tahun'];
        $id_lokasi[]=$value['id_lokasi'];
        $tahun[]=$value['tahun'];
    }
```